# svndumpfilter - unsupported dumpfile version

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump, svndumpfilter

I', trying to migrate a part of my SVN repository to new location. I dumped the whole repository and now try to filter out my folder of interest:

```
$ svndumpfilter include sandwiches < dumpfile > filtered-dumpfile
```

But then I got following error:

```
svndumpfilter: unsuported dump file version: 3
```

I came across [quite old article](http://creatingwithcode.com/howto/extracting-projects-from-shared-svn/) saying dump filter is not working if repository dump was created with `--deltas` flag.

**Question:** Is there any possibility to use `svndumpfilter` with dump file with deltas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. `svndumpfilter` can't operate with deltified dumps.

Check the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html):

> The second useful option is --deltas. This option causes svnadmin dump
>   to, instead of emitting full-text representations of file contents and
>   property lists, emit only deltas of those items against their previous
>   versions. This reduces (in some cases, drastically) the size of the
>   dump file that svnadmin dump creates. There are, however,
>   disadvantages to using this option—deltified dump files are more
>   CPU-intensive to create, **cannot be operated on by svndumpfilter**, and
>   tend not to compress as well as their nondeltified counterparts when
>   using third-party tools such as gzip and bzip2.

Comment: The obvious work-around is to avoid using the `--deltas` option -- or (if you don't have access to the original repository) import the dump into a temporary repository and export it again.